# Honda civic 2003 EX won't start when hot

Tags: honda, civic, cranks-wont-run, hot-start

I bought this car used a month ago. It has been working fine. 
prior to purchasing the car the previous owner told me he just changed the fuel pump so I know that is out of the question. It has had a check engine light once and it was for one of the spark plugs so I changed it.

Today while I was driving it, I noticed I had a hard time accelerating the car. It went away after a while and I was able to gas it fine. It wasn't until I parked it to gas up when it would not start. The starter would go but it would not start. I sat there with the hood up for 10 minutes then it turned on.

I'm not very familiar with this problem but from what I understand it is common.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The EX has a VTEC engine in it. I'm wondering if you've checked the oil to ensure it's up to level? I'm not sure this would affect it running or not, but might. I know the way the head is designed, there's a lot of oil which is left up there to lubricate the camshaft. Just throwing things out there.

Comment: Define hot. Is it normal engine operating temp? Is the interior cabin temp high? Have you checked for fuel pressure? Spark? Injector pulse?